# Installing Maya 2020 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

I'm one of those work-at-home-coronavirus people.

I'm hoping to install Maya 2020 on according to Autodesk's step-by-step instructions:
https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya/learn-explore/caas/simplecontent/content/installing-maya-2020-ubuntu.html

I'm pretty illiterate with this stuff- is there anyone patient enough to help me with this?

> 2. Download liXp6 from http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libx/libxp/libxp6_1.0.2-2_amd64.deb and install it
>
> `sudo apt-get ./libxp6_1.0.2-2_amd64.deb`

I get
$ sudo apt-get ./libxp6_1.0.2-2_amd64.deb
E: Invalid operation ./libxp6_1.0.2-2_amd64.deb

EDIT: Ok Solved! Thanks.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install ./libxp6_1.0.2-2_amd64.deb`

Comment: E: Unsupported file ./libxp6_1.0.2-2_amd64.deb given on commandline

Comment: Are you in the folder where you downloaded the file to?  It is normally downloaded to `~/Downloads`

Comment: Ah! It's not downloaded. Thanks for clue-ing me in. I thought this was a command that downloaded it for me. I got it using firefox, opened the package, and clicked 'Install'. I think that did it.  I think I'm good for step 2. Now I'm stuck on 5 (see edits above).

Comment: @TwirlySocrates Please ask one question at a time, this is not a forum but an Q&A website.

Comment: @TwirlySocrates I thought you had already solved that part.. ?

Comment: Yes, part 2 was solved here. I thought you were telling me to ask subsequent questions as a new post- so I did:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1218544/trouble-installing-maya-2020-in-ubuntu-18-04

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
wget http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libx/libxp/libxp6_1.0.2-2_amd64.deb 
sudo dpkg -i libxp6*.deb
```

Comment: I ended up downloading the file through firefox and installing it by double-clicking the package and hitting "install"... but yes I think this would have worked-  I needed to actually download the file. I think I'm good for step 2.
Now I'm stuck on step 5 (see edits above)... might be a similar issue, but I don't know where to get the library this time.