# Trouble installing Maya 2020 in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

I'm following these instructions:
https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya/learn-explore/caas/simplecontent/content/installing-maya-2020-ubuntu.html

I'm stuck on step five:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ./adlmflexnetclient-17.0.49-1_amd64.deb  
Reading package lists... Done  
E: Unsupported file ./adlmflexnetclient-17.0.49-1_amd64.deb given on commandline
```

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out:
The instructions substituted a dash for an underscore.

It says I should enter
$ sudo apt-get install ./adlmflexnetclient-17.0.49-1_amd64.deb
but it's supposed to say
$ sudo apt-get install ./adlmflexnetclient_17.0.49-1_amd64.deb

Comment: Thanks, man! I was getting mad over this. You literally saved my time and my life too.

Answer (score 0):

Mate, you're a covid hero in your own right. I hadn't been able to enter a serial number and get out of trial mode since I skipped over this .deb file and forgot - this solved it for me. Here's to a successful linux installation just in time for self isolation.